# while loop always print last inserted row result

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

Problem is while loop always showing last inserted row result. I've tried this below code to follow/unfollow button option. For example I'm a user id=1. I have already followed user id=4. Now, I want to follow user id=5. When i click follow button(id=5) it turns into Unfollow properly. But, I have already followed user id=4. That turns into Follow. This is my problem.

Then I tried `echo $following;`. it Prints 5555. That means last inserted data. But I want 45. I'm sure I've made a mistake in my while loop. But I don't know what I should change?

```
        <?php
                try
                {
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY Autoid");
                    $stmt->errorInfo();
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM followers ORDER BY Autoid");
                    $sth->errorInfo();
                    $sth->execute();
                    while($follow_row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                   {
                        $following = $follow_row['Following'];
                        $follower = $follow_row['Follower'];
                   }

                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                       {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['Autoid'] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['Name'] ."</td>";

                        // echo $row['Following'];
                        if($_SESSION['sesuname'] == $row['Username'])
                         {
                            echo "<td class='itsyou' >Its You ". $_SESSION['sesuname'] ."</td>";
                         }
                        else
                         {  
                            if(($follower == $_SESSION['sesid']) AND ($following != $row['Autoid']))
                            {
                               //echo "<td>true</td>";
                             echo $following;
                             echo "<td>";
                             echo "<form id='jsform' method='post' action='subscribe.php'>";
                             echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value=" . $row['Autoid'] . " />";
                             echo "<button class='follow' >Follow</button>";
                             echo "</form>";
                             echo "</td>";                             
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //echo "<td>false</td>";
                             echo "<td>";
                             echo "<form id='ufform' method='post' action='unsubscribe.php'>";
                             echo "<input type='hidden' name='uid' value=" . $row['Autoid'] . " />";
                             echo "<button class='follow' >UnFollow</button>";
                             echo "</form>";
                             echo "</td>";
                            }
                         }
                        echo "</tr>";
                     }
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                       'Database Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
    while($follow_row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
        $following = $follow_row['Following'];
        $follower = $follow_row['Follower'];
   }
```

Simply OVERWRITES `$following` and `$follower` every time you fetch a row, leaving you with the **LAST** row fetched in the variables. Perhaps you want something more like

```
    $following[] = $follow_row['Following'];
    $follower[] = $follow_row['Follower'];
             ^^--- append new row value to an array.
```

Comment: But now follow and unfollow is not working properly. I mean function(update and delete) is working properly. But it doesn't turn into Unfollow if i click Follow button.. it doesn't turn into Follow if i click Unfollow button. I'm using if else condition for that...

Comment: yes, because you're retrieving MULTIPLE values in your follower query, but treating the query as if it would only ever return ONE value. you need to fundamentally change the logic in your loops.